# How to display messages using the messages framework in Django using a background job?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, background-process

I am running background tasks in my Django app using [Django Background Tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is checking from a Django model if a particular deadline is crossed.

```
@background(schedule=10000)
def check_deadline(repeat=30000):
     # Check if deadline has crossed from DB
     # Return the record's title whose deadline has crossed
```

If the condition is satisfied, then the background task must send a message to any template that is being currently viewed. I am not sure how to send a message to the template from the background task.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Your job is running on the background, it's not associated with any request. Whose template would you send it to?

Comment: Is there no provision for the server to push messages to the frontend, no matter which template is being displayed?

Comment: You can use django channels. It may help you.

Comment: Or firebase or amazon SNS